# Make a console app where the output isn't linear

Tags: python, command-line

When I've made any type of command line based app before, the only method I've used to display output has been something like `print(stuff);` or `System.Console.print(moreStuff);`.

However, I have seen and used console applications (`nano` is an example) that take control of the whole console window.

I am writing a console app (in python) that I think may be suited to this approach.

So, how can I achieve this (in python) (and preferably so that it works on Windows and Linux)?

Does the technique have a name?

By linear I mean like this:

```
->Searching for files...
->10 files found...
->Analyzing files...
```

When I'd like something more like:

```
->Searching files in directory [current_dir_goes_here]
->10 files found
->Analyzing [filename.txt]
```

Comment: the library you are probably looking for is called curses.

Comment: I'm not exactly what you mean by "isn't linear", but if you're referring to treating the console like a UI with controls made up of characters on the screen, you might be interested in this: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Comment: Based on your edits, it sounds like the word you really wanted as "dynamic". No, I don't think this should be very difficult: You program knows the directory name and the file name, why *not* include it in your logging statement? And yes, now that I understand this, I think it would have made more sense on StackOverflow, but it will probably get closed there unless you have a code sample and a more specific problem (ask a moderator to migrate it if you reall want to).

Comment: I work on Windows and Linux, so I'd ideally like a solution that covers both.

Comment: You should really try Blessings (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/) which is an easy-to-use library to "replace" ncurses.